# SQL Server : use of # in date literal

Tags: sql, sql-server

In [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com%5C), I found the below code in [SQL section](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp).

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
```

I know we specify single quote for the date string like '07/04/1996'.

Can we also use # for the date string ? Does use of # has some significance?

Comment: For SQL Server, **definitely** just use the single quotes - and preferably the ISO-8601 formatting : `20160407` for 7th of April 2016 (`YYYYMMDD` format) to be independent of any regional settings. `#` is used by e.g. MS Access for dates, I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not valid SQL Server syntax:

```
with Orders as (
    select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as OrderDay
)
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
```

> Incorrect syntax near '#'.

The website does not mention anything about SQL Server by the way.

As per @marc_s' comment, this might be valid MS Access SQL syntax.

Comment: I believe the SQL in MS Access uses the `#` to denote dates

Comment: I just happened to find out now that in MSSQL another "unusual" form is possible: `{d'2010-07-01'}`